# Adding dropbox feature on my android app?

Tags: android, dropbox

I have found the documentation available at https://www.dropbox.com/developers really not helpful! 
I even downloaded the sdk available at their site.
My project requires the use of dropbox and enable my app to upload images onto a folder in the account. 
Can anyone help give me relevant info that could be really handy for my project.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like Android Dropbox SDK documentation has been added now. One can see the 'Tutorial' and 'Docs' for Android (and other platforms) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        api = getAPI();

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();


        File f=null;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
        {
             //SDcard is available
               f=new File("/sdcard/test.txt");
               if (!f.exists()) 
               {
                //File does not exists
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }


        }

         api.putFile("dropbox", "/Project", f);
```

Comment: This is done in the `displayAccountInfo(DropboxAPI.Account account)` method.

Comment: so i just need to initiate the dropboxSample.java with above code in dsipalyAccounInfo for file upload without gui?

Comment: Not really, I just gave you an example of how you could upload a file. If you want to upload without passing trough the gui authentication you must modify that example completely or create your own using Dropbox api. I cannot write the whole code ... I don't have time, but it's not hard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Dropbox Android API sample project ? From there, once logged in you can `api.putFile("dropbox", "/Project", file);` where `/Project` is the folder in your dropbox account and the `file` is the file you want to upload. That sample project can be modified to skip gui authentication and do it from code. If you need a full code sample please reply.